# How to read strings with tag <xliff:g> from xml file by python3

Tags: python

What I have: Lines with tag `<xliff:g>` in xml file like:

```
<string name="AAAAAAA" msgid="XXXXXXX">"Activity <xliff:g id="BBBBBBB">%1$s</xliff:g> isn\'t responding."\n\n"Do you want to close it?"</string>
```

What I need: Reading the entire string the same as:

```
Activity %1$s isn't responding.\n\nDo you want to close it?
```

Coud you please help?

I tried to use xml.dom.minidom.

```
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(xmlfile)
strings = dom.getElementsByTagName('string')
for string in strings:
    rText = string.childNodes[0].nodeValue
    print(rText)
```

The result is "Activity

Comment: Have you tried telling the XML parser about the namespace?

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow isn't a "Here's what I need, please write it for me" site. You have to try and do it yourself, and we'll help along the way. If you just want someone to write scripts for you, my rate is $200/hr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that  element is part of a bigger file. For example:

```
<strings xmlns:xliff="some-name-space">
  <string name="AAAAAAA" msgid="XXXXXXX">"Activity <xliff:g id="BBBBBBB">%1$s</xliff:g> isn\'t responding."\n\n"Do you want to close it?"</string>
  <string name="AAAAAAA" msgid="XXXXXXX">"Another <xliff:g id="BBBBBBB">%1$s</xliff:g>message</string>
</strings>
```

using the minidom is as good as any other framework. Open the file and iterate through all  elements. For each element call the function `get_text`. Get text defined below recursively returns the content (nodeValue) of all elements.

```
import xml.dom.minidom as md
dom = md.parse('wu.xml')
strings = dom.getElementsByTagName('string')
for string in strings:
    print get_text(string)

def get_text(el):
    """get_text
    For text nodes, returns the text. For element nodes, recursively call the
    function to aggregate all the text nodes into a string"""           
    msg = ''
    for n in el.childNodes:
        if n.nodeType == n.TEXT_NODE:
            msg += n.nodeValue
        elif n.nodeType == n.ELEMENT_NODE:
            msg += get_text(n)
    return msg
```

There are many other ways to do it.

Comment: It works! You are magician. :)
Thanks a lot for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XML parser like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.crummy.com%2Fsoftware%2FBeautifulSoup%2F&ei=p8e-Uc63B8SYiAev3IDoCg&usg=AFQjCNHAxwplurFOBqg5cehWQEVKi-TuLQ&sig2=yg5CZigipB_ctpkXF6afVw&bvm=bv.47883778,d.aGc), which is extremely easy to use (in my opinion):

```
>>> myxml = "thexmlyouposted"
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> soup = BS(myxml, 'xml')
>>> print soup.find('string').text
"Activity %1$s isn't responding."

"Do you want to close it?"
```

Comment: dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse(xmlfile)
strings = dom.getElementsByTagName('string')
for string in strings:
    rText = string.childNodes[0].nodeValue
    print(rText)
The result is "Activity

Comment: @WUYinghui I don't know about that, sorry